# I want distinct numbers with choice as columns using datetime ascending order

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

there is a table with

```
1001  vsp,science,BBA  25-05-2020
1001  vsp,Maths,Btech  26-05-2020
1001  vsp,Maths,Btech  27-05-2020
1002  hyd,science,BBA  24-05-2020
1002  blr,Maths,Btech  25-05-2020
```

I want

```
1001  vsp,science,bba   vsp,Maths,Btech    vsp,Maths,Btech
```

Comment: "I want" is not a question, have you tried anything, where are you stuck?

Comment: What happened with the 1002 values? Don't you want them too?

Comment: yes i want 1002 also but using datetime but not in display

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I have tried with pivot but i cant place any aggregate fun in that

Comment: MS sql server I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need one of my favorite combo to achieve your goal:

- CTE (to create proper sub request): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql
- ROW_NUMBER (to rank your rows): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql
- PIVOT (to pivot your results): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

And now the solution:

```
WITH orderedCourse AS
(
    SELECT  GroupId,
            CourseLabel,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY CourseDate) AS CourseNumber
    FROM @myCourses
)
SELECT TOP (1) GroupId, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM    
        (
            SELECT  GroupId,
                    CourseLabel,
                    CourseNumber
            FROM orderedCourse
        ) AS src
        PIVOT
        (
            MIN(CourseLabel) -- default agregate
            FOR CourseNumber IN ([1], [2], [3], [4] /*... if you have more courses by group*/)
        ) AS pvt
ORDER BY GroupId
```

Which give the result:

```
1001  vsp,science,BBA  vsp,Maths,Btech  vsp,Maths,Btech  NULL
```

I used this code to declare the table:

```
INSERT INTO @myCourses
SELECT 1001, 'vsp,science,BBA', CAST('25-05-2020' AS date) UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 'vsp,Maths,Btech', CAST('26-05-2020' AS date) UNION ALL
SELECT 1001, 'vsp,Maths,Btech', CAST('27-05-2020' AS date) UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 'yd,science,BBA', CAST('24-05-2020' AS date) UNION ALL
SELECT 1002, 'blr,Maths,Btech', CAST('25-05-2020' AS date);

SELECT  GroupId,
        CourseLabel,
        CourseDate,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GroupId ORDER BY CourseDate) AS CourseNumber
FROM @myCourses;
```

Comment: I tried SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT registration_number,
          concat(campus1, ' ,', branch1,' ,',course1) as choice ,dt_time
    FROM tbl_branch_selected
) AS SourceTable PIVOT(Max(dt_time) FOR choice IN([pre1],
                                                         [pre2],
                                                         [pre3],
                                                         [pre4],
                                                         [pre5],[pre6])) AS PivotTable  but getting null data

Comment: you have null values, because pre1 to pre6 are not values in the results of your first select, where you have the concat clause. This is why I added a ROW_NUMBER clause in my sample, to have fixed values for the pivot, and ordering by dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation with `row_number()`:

```
select col1,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then col2 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then col2 end),
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then col2 end)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col3) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by col1;
```

This has nothing to do with string aggregation.  It also doesn't require a plethora of subqueries and CTEs.